# Throwing error while debug and run PO command in Xcode 12

Tags: debugging, swift5, xcode12

When I am running application on simulator or device and try to use PO command during debug. Xcode is throwing error instead of printing value. It is happening after I have updated Xcode 12.

> error: virtual filesystem overlay file

> /all-product-headers.yaml' not found

> error: couldn't IRGen expression. Please check the above error messages for possible root causes.

[image]

What is the solution for this ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to /Users/<YOUR_USER>/Library/Developer/Xcode/ and delete "DerivedData" folder.

If in the path of the missing file is the name of a framework e.g. **Usabilla**.build/Release-iphonesimulator/**Usabilla**.build/all-product-headers.yaml
Try using an older version, using version 6.4.7 of Usabilla fixed the issue for me.

If the above fixes don't work, here are some info that might help:
https://steipete.com/posts/couldnt-irgen-expression/